# Java Generics on Class Method

Tags: java, generics, methods

Is Java Generics possible on a Method Level. I wrote the below code without compilation errors, but it seems, its not possible to run the below code as expected.

```
public class ConvertAttrib {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Number> T convertNumeric(final Object object) {
        if((object instanceof Integer)||(object instanceof Long)||(object instanceof Double)||(object instanceof Float)) {
            return (T) object;
        } else if(object instanceof String) {
            Object obj = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(object));
            return ConvertAttrib.convertNumeric(obj);
        } else if(object instanceof Boolean) {
            return ConvertAttrib.convertNumeric((Boolean)object == true?1:0); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Long(5);
        Number numeric = ConvertAttrib.convertNumeric(obj);
        System.out.println(numeric);
    //      Integer num = ConvertAttrib.convertNumeric<Integer>(obj);
    //Removing the above comment gives compilation error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the specific compiler error you're getting?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. try `.<Integer>convertNumeric`

Comment: or just `Integer number = ConvertAttrib.convertNumeric(obj);`

Answer (score 1):

My syntax was wrong, in order to type a generic method call use the following syntax :

```
ConvertAttrib.<Integer>convertNumeric(obj);
```

Comment: This answer shouldn't be up-voted since it isn't OP solution but he gained it through comments.

Comment: The answer was written by the OP, it was most recently edited by another user though.